# Makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target `genesha.main.java.Jni.class', needed by `FileOperationsLibrary.h'. Stop." in Eclipse (Windows)

Tags: windows, eclipse, makefile, java-native-interface, javah

I have problem with my makefile. I'm working on Eclipse in Windows and my file structure is like below (project path: D:/workspace):

```
Genesha    
|
|___bin          
|     |_genesha                  
|             |_main
|                  |_java
|___src                  |__Jni.class
      |_genesha                  
              |_main
                   |_jni
                        |__makefile
```

When I in cmd from localization of makefile (D:\workspace\Genesha\src\genesha\main\jni) I used command:

```
javah -o FileOperationsLibrary.h -jni -classpath ../../../../bin genesha.main.java.Jni
```

it works correctly. But when I used my makefile, I have following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `genesha.main.java.Jni.class', needed by `FileOperationsLibrary.h'.  Stop.
```

I was searching long time error and now I have not idea what's wrong here...

EDIT: my makefile

```
FileOperationsLibrary.h: genesha.main.java.Jni.class
    javah -o FileOperationsLibrary.h -jni -classpath ../../../../bin genesha.main.java.Jni
```

EDIT 2: Finally, thanks to MadScientist my make file code is:

```
FileOperationsLibrary.h: ../../../../bin/genesha/main/java/Jni.class
javah -o FileOperationsLibrary.h -jni -classpath ../../../../bin genesha.main.java.Jni
```

Thank you a lot for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that in your makefile somewhere you have a target `FileOperationsLibrary.h` that lists `genesha.main.java.Jni.class` as a prerequisite, something like:

```
FileOperationsLibrary.h: genesha.main.java.Jni.class
```

The file `genesha.main.java.Jni.class` does not exist, so make tries to find a way to build it.  However there are no rules defined in the makefile that tell it how to build that file, so you get that error message.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I'm running this file in eclipse by RMB in file->Make targets->Build. I know, there a lot of problems like mine, but resolutions wasn't useful in my case.

Comment: Excellent; your edit confirms my explanation of the error message.  This explains why you are seeing that error.